# Calling a task-based asynchronous one way callback method from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, callback, oneway

I have a WCF service which uses a callback contract to notify the clients, similar to this

```
public interface IClientCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void NotifySomething();
}
```

and the service code calling it similar to this

```
void NotifySomething()
{
    try
    {
        this.callback.NotifySomething();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception and eat it
    }
}
```

Note that by design the callback notification is **optional**, i.e. nice to have, but not required. That's why it's marked as `OneWay` and the implementation eats exceptions.

Due to some misunderstanding we were thinking that would be enough for having a non blocking fire and forget method. But of course that wasn't true, so under some circumstances it's blocking for a while, which is causing problems because it's called from inside thread synchronized block. So we decided to make it asynchronous by changing the definition as follows

```
public interface IClientCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    Task NotifySomething();
}
```

I have no problem with client implementation, my question is how to call it from the service. Here is what I'm thinking to do

```
async void NotifySomething()
{
    try
    {
        await this.callback.NotifySomething();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        // Unwrap, log the exception(s) and eat it
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception and eat it
    }
}
```

Now, since everyone is saying `async void` is not a good practice, is it ok to use it here? What other options do I have? What is the recommended way to perform this in the WCF service context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you have written it is pretty safe as it handles the exceptions. You could also write a reusable extension method to do that so that you don't need to repeat it.

Perhaps something like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void FireAndForget(this Task task)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(t => 
        {
            // log exceptions
            t.Exception.Handle((ex) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return true;
            });

        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }
}

public async Task FailingOperation()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    throw new Exception("Error");
}   

void Main()
{
    FailingOperation().FireAndForget();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ned, very interesting approach. Outside this, looks like its how I was thinking - I've asked because didn't find any official source, and didn't want to just use "try and see what happens" approach. I was thinking there would be more attention from the community since this seems to be now the recommended way for defining WCF async methods, but anyway. Thanks again for spending your time on this! Cheers from Bg.