# WCF duplex channel with callback having async operation contract

Tags: c#, wcf, callback, async-await, duplex

I have a WCF duplex channel. In the callback, the WCF service shall notify the client and asynchronously wait till the client has completely processed the notification.

In this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451018/calling-a-task-based-asynchronous-one-way-callback-method-from-wcf-service) I found how I could implement the callback interface:

```
public interface IClientCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    Task NotifySomething();
}

// call from WCF service
await clientCallback.NotifySomething();
```

This is exacly what I need, but I'm a little surprised, because I thought that one way operations can only have `void` as return type.

See also this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute.IsOneWay);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true):

> One-way methods must not return a value or have ref or out parameters

So is the above code really the correct solution for my problem?

Comment: asynchronously wait ..What do you mean?.Can you be a little brief .

Comment: Method that returns `Task` (and not `Task<Something>`) is asynchornous analog of method that returns `void`, so that's fine. Note that for one-way operations no response is expected from the other side, so it will not "wait till the client has completely processed the notification".

Comment: @Hameed: With "asynchronously wait" I mean that the service is not blocked while it waits that the client has processed the notification.

Comment: @Evk: So how long would the `await clientCallback.NotifySomething()` actually wait?

Comment: I did not touch WCF for years so my knowledge about that is rusty. That said, I would expect it will wait until request message is sent to client, but it will not wait for response from client to be received.